# Unity 3D Google Cardboard Camera

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, stereoscopy

I'm experimenting with Google Cardboard in Unity 3D to create a basic VR game. I'm having trouble figuring out which prefab is the stereoscopic cardboard camera.

I've found several videos that claim to show me, but when I look for the prefabs names they describe, I can't find them in my list. In the comments of [one video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIATVY0sXuU) someone suggested it was called GVREditorEmulator, which I have in my prefabs, but doesn't provide a camera when I play the scene (even on the Unity Remote 5 app).

Can someone tell me what the Google Cardboard Camera prefab is called?

I'm using Unity 3D version 2017.3.0f3 and Google Cardboard SDK for Unity v1.130.1 from [this repository](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/releases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag **GVREditorEmulator.prefab** in to your scene, and go to Build Settings then switch platform to iOS or Android, then go to Player Settings and click on the  OtherSettings [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/j3r2e5) then click on the Virtual Reality moved to XR settings field, then you will get this screen [Screenshot2](https://prnt.sc/j3r2vp), check Virtual Reality Supported and on plus sign chose Cardboard. Now you can play scene (hold Alt and move mouse to simulate movement of the head).

**Note:** Editor doesn't show the stereo view anymore but it will be there when you build your game on the target device.

Comment: "When you build you game on the target device" Do you mean build it to an .apk for my android that it will appear in stereoscopic view? Because I've tried your suggestion before and connected my Android tablet via USB and it didn't work. Also, if I don't have the main camera  on the scene, then it doesn't register a camera at all

Comment: If you build for Android then i mean on .apk and for iOS .xcodeproj. The MainCamera must be on scene because GVREditorEmulator only allows you to simulate movement of the head in editor. But Unity natively insert stereoscopic view when you check Virtual Reality Supported box. Pay attention in XR settings to Stereo Rendering Method must be seted to Multi Pass. https://prnt.sc/j3src2